# Djikstra with 2 factors in python3

Tags: python-3.x, dijkstra

So we have a normal weighted bidirectional graph, but along with the weight there is another factor x that has a higher priority than weight. I have to find the shortest path from 1 node to another without having x being higher than a certain number.

Apparently you're supposed to use a 2d matrix to represent if you were to take a path to a node of a certain distance, how much damage would you take. For example, if you are at node 1 take a path of weight 3 and x(5) to node 2, matrix[5][2] = 3

My question is how would you know which value to assign to a node in the priority queue. For example, if there were 2 paths to a certain node, one of weight 3 and x(4), and another of weight 4 and x(3).

Comment: Could you convert your x factor to cost as well? Depending on what you are doing,Multiply it by a big number.

Comment: i don't think so, this problem is pretty much this https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc15s4

Comment: I took a look at your link and I still think the routes that make your ship wrecked can be avoided by assigning a big number, still shortest path works. I don’t know what network analysis library you are using but most of them accept stop node or stop arcs, though they use big numbers for cost of forbidden arcs or nodes to model to stoppages

Comment: I found this solution online using dp but I don't understand how it works, can someone explain please?https://repl.it/repls/PalatableFrightenedChords